My table is too wide for the page
I am trying to get this table to fit on the page. I have changed the orientation to landscape, splitting text over multiple rows and setting specific widths for each column but nothing seems to work.
Unfortunately I have had to blank out the text for privacy reasons, but I have tried to keep the same distribution of text.
My code is below and I have attached a screenshot to visually depict the problem.
EDIT: I have updated the code so that you can run a test yourself.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\newcommand{\minitab}[2][l]{\begin{tabular}{#1}#2\end{tabular}}

\title{test}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{table*}[ht]
  \caption{Summary of included work.}
  \centering
  \label{tab:summary}

  \begin{tabular}{ | c | c | c | c | c | c | c | c | c |}
  \hline
   \multirow{3}{*}{\minitab[c]{\textbf{Xxxxx}\\ \textbf{Xxxxxxxx}}} & \multirow{3}{*}{\textbf{XXX}} & \multirow{3}{*}{\minitab[c]{\textbf{Xxxxxx}\\ \textbf{Xxxx}}} & \multirow{3}{*}{\minitab[c]{\textbf{Xxx}\\ (\textbf{Xxxxxxx})}} & \multirow{3}{*}{\minitab[c]{\textbf{Xxxxxxxx}\\ \textbf{Xxxxxx}}} & \multirow{3}{*}{\minitab[c]{\textbf{Xxxxxxxxxx}\\ \textbf{Xxxxxxxx}}} & \multirow{3}{*}{\minitab[c]{\textbf{XX}\\ \textbf{Xxxxxx}}} & \multirow{3}{*}{\minitab[c]{\textbf{Xxxxxxx}\\ \textbf{Xxxxxxxx}}} & \textbf{XXXX} \\
    & & & & & & & & \textbf{Xxxxxxx} \\
    & & & & & & & & \textbf{Xxxxxxx} \\
   \hline
   \multirow{3}{*}{\minitab[c]{Xxxxxx xx xx xxxxx\\XXX}} & \multirow{3}{*}{Y} & \multirow{3}{*}{$XXX$} & \multirow{3}{*}{$XXX$} & \multirow{3}{*}{\minitab[c]{$XXX$\\Xxxxxx}} & \multirow{3}{*}{XXX-X} & \multirow{3}{*}{XX} & XXX-X, & \multirow{3}{*}{-} \\
    & & & & & & & XX, & \\
    & & & & & & & XXX & \\
   \hline
    Xxxxxxxx xx xx XXXXX: & \multirow{5}{*}{Y} & \multirow{5}{*}{XXX} & \multirow{5}{*}{XXX} & XXX & \multirow{2}{*}{XXX-X} & \multirow{2}{*}{XX} & XXX-X, XX & \multirow{2}{*}{-} \\
   Xxxxx xx xx XXXX & & & & Xxxxxx & & & XXX & \\
   Xxxxxxxx xx xx XXXXX & & & & Xxxxxx & & & XXX & \\
   Xxxxx xxx Xxxxxxxxx XXXXX & & & & Xxxxxx & & & XXX & \\
   Xxxxxxxx xx xx XXXXX & & & & Xxxxxx & & & XXX & \\
   \hline

  \end{tabular}
\end{table*}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}





In particular, do please reveal (a) which document class you employ, (b) the dimensions of the text block (e.g., show the values of \textwidth and \textheight), and (c) the definition of \minitab.

Sorry both, I have updated the post now so you should have a better idea of what I am experiencing. I am not sure what the \textwidth or \textheight are, I haven't manually set them.

Use a smaller size before the tabular (e.g.: \footnotesize), and/or reduce \tabcolsep (e.g.: 1 mm) and use booktabs package and do not add ugly vertical rules. Above all, do not use \minitab to split the cell. Instead, learn what is the p column (texdoc array, page 2) and take the look to the several packages to make complex tables as tabulary or tabularray . Finally, remember that there are not good tricks to solve the issue of excessive contents.  Then the solutions is redesign the table, or better, do not use a table but other format (e.g.: a list).

Just make it smaller:



\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\newcommand{\minitab}[2][l]{\begin{tabular}{@{}#1@{}}#2\end{tabular}}

\title{test}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}
  \caption{Summary of included work.}
  \centering\small\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
  \label{tab:summary}

  \begin{tabular}{@{} | c | c | c | c | c | c | c | c | c |@{}}
  \hline
   \multirow{3}{*}{\minitab[c]{\textbf{Xxxxx}\\ \textbf{Xxxxxxxx}}} & \multirow{3}{*}{\textbf{XXX}} & \multirow{3}{*}{\minitab[c]{\textbf{Xxxxxx}\\ \textbf{Xxxx}}} & \multirow{3}{*}{\minitab[c]{\textbf{Xxx}\\ (\textbf{Xxxxxxx})}} & \multirow{3}{*}{\minitab[c]{\textbf{Xxxxxxxx}\\ \textbf{Xxxxxx}}} & \multirow{3}{*}{\minitab[c]{\textbf{Xxxxxxxxxx}\\ \textbf{Xxxxxxxx}}} & \multirow{3}{*}{\minitab[c]{\textbf{XX}\\ \textbf{Xxxxxx}}} & \multirow{3}{*}{\minitab[c]{\textbf{Xxxxxxx}\\ \textbf{Xxxxxxxx}}} & \textbf{XXXX} \\
    & & & & & & & & \textbf{Xxxxxxx} \\
    & & & & & & & & \textbf{Xxxxxxx} \\
   \hline
   \multirow{3}{*}{\minitab[c]{Xxxxxx xx xx xxxxx\\XXX}} & \multirow{3}{*}{Y} & \multirow{3}{*}{$XXX$} & \multirow{3}{*}{$XXX$} & \multirow{3}{*}{\minitab[c]{$XXX$\\Xxxxxx}} & \multirow{3}{*}{XXX-X} & \multirow{3}{*}{XX} & XXX-X, & \multirow{3}{*}{-} \\
    & & & & & & & XX, & \\
    & & & & & & & XXX & \\
   \hline
    Xxxxxxxx xx xx XXXXX: & \multirow{5}{*}{Y} & \multirow{5}{*}{XXX} & \multirow{5}{*}{XXX} & XXX & \multirow{2}{*}{XXX-X} & \multirow{2}{*}{XX} & XXX-X, XX & \multirow{2}{*}{-} \\
   Xxxxx xx xx XXXX & & & & Xxxxxx & & & XXX & \\
   Xxxxxxxx xx xx XXXXX & & & & Xxxxxx & & & XXX & \\
   Xxxxx xxx Xxxxxxxxx XXXXX & & & & Xxxxxx & & & XXX & \\
   Xxxxxxxx xx xx XXXXX & & & & Xxxxxx & & & XXX & \\
   \hline

  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}



Awesome! Thanks David!

This is probably simpler solution for you, however for your table I prepare quite simpler code using tabularray package where your command \minitab as well the most of \multirow cells are superfluous.
